# Opening the first accordion on page load

Tags: javascript, css, accordion

can you help me?

How can I open the first accordion automatically on page load? It does not matter if it's with javascript or css.

Codepen: codepen.io/fainder/pen/AydHJ

I really do not know how to do this. I hope that you understand what is my point here.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your code, the simple constraint, and the fact that you're using jQuery, the simplest solution is to trigger a [click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) on the [first](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) match for `.link` on document load. This should do the trick at the end of your main function:

```
$(".link:first").click();
```

It's quick and dirty and should get the job done. You may need to adjust it with a more specific selector if you're using the `.link` class anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Okay it's very easy, you just need to add "open" class to the first `<li>` tag, and then add `style="display:block;` to the submenu :

```
  <li class="open">
    <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-database"></i>Web Design<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
    <ul class="submenu" style="display: block;">
      <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

check this : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GxwraM